# Fun with row_number() - Redshift Postgres - Time sequence and restarting numbering

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am looking to number streaks within my data, the goal is to find where at least 3 consecutive streaks are flagged by the np.

Here is a subset of my data:

```
drop table if exists bi_test;
create table test (id varchar(12),rd date,np decimal);

insert into test
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-07-25'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-01'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-08'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-15'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-22'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-29'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-05'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-12'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-19'::date, 1;
```

I am hoping to use row_number() and count(), but it doesn't seem to be giving me the result I want.

```
select
    *
   ,row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.rd) all_ctr
   ,count(t.id) over (partition by t.id) all_count
   ,row_number() over (partition by t.id,t.np order by t.rd) np_counter
   ,count(t.id) over (partition by t.id,t.np) np_non_np
from
    bi_adhoc.test t
order by
    t.rd;
```

Here are my results, and the desired result:

```
id          rd              np    all_ctr   all_count   np_counter  np_non_np   **Desired**
aaabbbccc   7/25/2016        0      1          9           1           6           **1**
aaabbbccc   8/1/2016         0      2          9           2           6           **2**
aaabbbccc   8/8/2016         0      3          9           3           6           **3**
aaabbbccc   8/15/2016        0      4          9           4           6           **4**
aaabbbccc   8/22/2016        1      5          9           1           3           **1**
aaabbbccc   8/29/2016        0      6          9           5           6           **1**
aaabbbccc   9/5/2016         1      7          9           2           3           **1**
aaabbbccc   9/12/2016        0      8          9           6           6           **1**
aaabbbccc   9/19/2016        1      9          9           3           3           **1**
```

Comment: Where is your np_flag column and what values does it have?

Comment: My apologies, I edited np_flag down to np to make the table more readable. np is binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I added some additional data to help fully illustrate the problem...

```
drop table if exists bi_adhoc.test;
create table bi_adhoc.test (id varchar(12),period date,hit decimal);

insert into bi_adhoc.test
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-07-25'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-01'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-08'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-15'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-22'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-08-29'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-05'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-12'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-19'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-09-26'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-10-03'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-10-10'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-10-17'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-10-24'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-10-31'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-11-07'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-11-14'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-11-21'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-11-28'::date, 0 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-12-05'::date, 1 union all
select 'aaabbbccc', '2016-12-12'::date, 1;
```

Then the key was to figure out what a streak was and how to identify each streak so I could partition the data to have something to partition the data.

```
select
    *
    ,case
        when t1.hit = 1 then row_number() over (partition by t1.id,t1.hit_partition order by t1.period)
        when t1.hit = 0 then row_number() over (partition by t1.id,t1.miss_partition order by t1.period)
    else null
end desired
from
(
select
    *
    ,row_number() over (partition by  t.id order by t.id,t.period)
    ,case
        when t.hit = 1 then row_number() over (partition by t.id, t.hit order by t.period)
        else null
    end hit_counter
    ,case
        when t.hit = 1 then row_number() over (partition by  t.id order by t.id,t.period) - row_number() over (partition by t.id, t.hit order by t.period)
        else null
    end hit_partition
    ,case
        when t.hit = 0 then row_number() over (partition by t.id, t.hit order by t.period)
        else null
    end miss_counter
    ,case
        when t.hit = 0 then row_number() over (partition by  t.id order by t.id,t.period) - row_number() over (partition by t.id, t.hit order by t.period)
        else null
    end miss_partition
from
    bi_adhoc.test t
) t1
order by
    t1.id
    ,t1.period;
```

The result of this:

```
id          period          hit     row_number  hit_counter hit_partition   miss_counter    miss_partition  desired
aaabbbccc   2016-07-25      0       1           NULL        NULL            1               0               1
aaabbbccc   2016-08-01      0       2           NULL        NULL            2               0               2
aaabbbccc   2016-08-08      0       3           NULL        NULL            3               0               3
aaabbbccc   2016-08-15      1       4           1           3               NULL            NULL            1
aaabbbccc   2016-08-22      1       5           2           3               NULL            NULL            2
aaabbbccc   2016-08-29      0       6           NULL        NULL            4               2               1
aaabbbccc   2016-09-05      0       7           NULL        NULL            5               2               2
aaabbbccc   2016-09-12      1       8           3           5               NULL            NULL            1
aaabbbccc   2016-09-19      0       9           NULL        NULL            6               3               1
aaabbbccc   2016-09-26      1       10          4           6               NULL            NULL            1
aaabbbccc   2016-10-03      1       11          5           6               NULL            NULL            2
aaabbbccc   2016-10-10      1       12          6           6               NULL            NULL            3
aaabbbccc   2016-10-17      1       13          7           6               NULL            NULL            4
aaabbbccc   2016-10-24      1       14          8           6               NULL            NULL            5
aaabbbccc   2016-10-31      0       15          NULL        NULL            7               8               1
aaabbbccc   2016-11-07      0       16          NULL        NULL            8               8               2
aaabbbccc   2016-11-14      0       17          NULL        NULL            9               8               3
aaabbbccc   2016-11-21      0       18          NULL        NULL            10              8               4
aaabbbccc   2016-11-28      0       19          NULL        NULL            11              8               5
aaabbbccc   2016-12-05      1       20          9           11              NULL            NULL            1
aaabbbccc   2016-12-12      1       21          10          11              NULL            NULL            2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to calculate the lag (np) value in a CTE, and then compare the current np and lagged np to detect a streak. This may not be the most optimal way, but seems to work fine.

```
with source_cte as 
(
select
    *
   ,row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.rd) row_num
   ,lag(np,1) over (partition by t.id order by t.rd) as prev_np
from
    bi_adhoc.test t
)
, streak_cte as
(
select
    *,
    case when np=prev_np or prev_np is NULL then 1 else 0 end as is_streak
from 
    source_cte
)
select 
    *, 
    case when is_streak=1 then dense_rank() over (partition by id, is_streak order by rd) else 1 end as desired
from 
    streak_cte 
order by 
    rd;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Crap, unfortunately this was not what I needed after applying this to the entire data set. I was hoping to number the streaks in the columns... I did come up with a solution: